# Dealing with Null in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a reader like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var item = new Product
        {
            _x1 = reader.GetString(0),
            _x2 = reader.GetString(1),
            _x3 = reader.GetString(2),
            _x4 = reader.GetDateTime(3)
        };
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

But sometimes the database has some `NULL` values and I get a data are null exception, how can I deal with it?

Comment: Where the null exception appears? Anyway, put a `if (reader != null` or inside a `try/catch`

Comment: Can you make the x variables nullable?

Comment: @Tico The exception fires when im creating the new Product object.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I did that and still not working: public DateTime? _x3{ get; set; }

Comment: Yeah now that I think about it the reader.GetString() still throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely one of your column values is DBNull.  You do not check for that.

I use a series of extension methods when reading a column that might have a null value.  If the base type is not nullable, the return value is the nullable variant of the original type.

```
public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
{
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetString(ordinal);
}


public static DateTime? GetDateTimeOrNull(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
{
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem you have here is that .NET cannot cast "NULL" to a string when you call reader.GetString(). To solve your problem, you must determine what you want to do if the value in the data reader is NULL and provide this in your programming code. Do you want to use an empty string? Do you want to use null? do you want an exception?

I would suggest writing an Extension Method for the DataReader class to create a new function that encapsulates your desired logic. This is an example:

```
public static string GetStringOrEmptyString(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
{
    if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal)) {
        // if its DBNULL, return empty string
        return "";
    } else {
        // otherwise return thew value as string
        return reader.GetString(ordinal);
    }
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
var item = new Product
{
    _x1 = reader.GetStringOrEmptyString(0),
    _x2 = reader.GetStringOrEmptyString(1),
    _x3 = reader.GetStringOrEmptyString(2),
    _x4 = reader.GetDateTime(3)
};
```